# Consistent estimate of an interval

Tags: asymptotics, consistency

Suppose I have an interval $[a,b]$, where $a$ is known and $b$ is unknown. Suppose I have a consistent estimator for $b$ denoted as $\widehat{b}$ so that $\widehat{b}=b+o_{p}(1)$. My question: is the resulting $[a,\widehat{b}]$ a consistent estimator for $[a,b]$ in the following sense:

$Pr([a,b]=[a,\widehat{b}])\rightarrow 1$ (as sample size $n\rightarrow \infty$)?

My guess is yes, as $\widehat{b}=b$ implies $[a,b]=[a,\widehat{b}]$ so

$Pr(\widehat{b}=b)\leq Pr([a,b]=[a,\widehat{b}])$ and $Pr(\widehat{b}=b)\rightarrow 1$. Correct?

Comment: I cannot understand this question because, since (given $a$ is known) $b$ and $\hat b$ provide full information about the interval and its estimate, there appears to be no distinction between the notations "$\Pr([a,b]=[a,\hat b])$" and "$\Pr(b=\hat b).$" Could you explain what the intended distinction is?

Comment: I guess you are right, they are the same.

Comment: If that's so, then consider the mean of any sample of a continuous distribution: with probability zero that estimator equals the true mean.  A sequence of zeros does not converge to $1.$

Comment: @whuber Agree, I saw where I went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @whuber Another question:  what can we say about the convergence of the estimated set $[a,\widehat{b}]$ to $[a,b]$? Does it converge under some different criterion or in a different sense (instead of equal to the true interval with probability going to 1)?

Comment: The interval is a red herring--all your statements are merely statements about $\hat b.$

Comment: @whuber Fair enough. What if we consider $[\widehat{a},\widehat{b}]$, where $\widehat{a}$ and $\widehat{b}$ are consistent estimate for $a$ and $b$ respectively?

Comment: Same answer: you're just using a different notation for the bivariate ordered pair $(\hat a,\hat b),$ which you have supposed consistently estimates $(a,b).$

Comment: @whuber. You are right. What I wrote is no different from the consistency of a random vector.